# Where can I get the source files for Firefox about:home page?

Tags: firefox

I am using Mozilla Firefox and I like the `about:home` page layout. Is there a GitHub or a repository to get the source code?

I want to convert it into a WordPress base theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is located in the [`mozilla-central` repository](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/) which contains all Firefox code, currently under [`/browser/base/content/abouthome/`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/9677eb19a6a5/browser/base/content/abouthome/). You can find it in the [GitHub copy of the `mozilla-centra` repository](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/tree/master/browser/base/content/abouthome) as well of course.

The license used is [Mozilla Public License Version 2.0](http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/) by the way, please make sure to comply with its terms (most likely boils down to keeping the MPL header in the relevant files of your theme).